# Is there a way we can export the workflows created in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I have created a workflow and I want to migrate it another account.
Can it be exported in some file format?

I tried finding the options but got any.

Answer (score 0):

You've 2 options through the **SuiteCloud Development Framework** or **SuiteBundler**.

1. For SuiteBundler just follow this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3374254.html).
2. For account customization with SDF - [SuiteCloud Development Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/chapter_4702629975.html)

- make sure you've [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed.
- create a new npm project: `npm init`
- install the [SuiteCloud CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oracle/suitecloud-cli) tools: `npm install @oracle/suitecloud-cli --save-dev`
- update your package.json including the following script commands.

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "suitecloud account:setup -i",
    "import": "suitecloud object:import -i",
    "deploy": "suitecloud project:deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@oracle/suitecloud-cli": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

- setup your account: `npm run setup`
- import your workflow objects (xml files): `npm run import`
- create a second project, setup similar to above but for the other account, copy over the
  xml files, and deploy them to the new environment: `npm run deploy`